# Split out jquery code from html that is echo'd in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, echo

So I'm just dabbling in this and most likely doing it wrong. But it's a proof of concept so I can get the powers that be to get someone to do it right.
I am using a php script for login and for posting variables from forms.

The problem: I am echocing out an html code that includes the css, html, and jquery scripts all in one file.  Which is fine for the css and html portion, but the jquery stuff doesn't work.

Is there a way to place the jquery portion in my php script to make it function, or does it need to be split out and referenced/loaded in the html.  (I believe that is the correct way, but I don't know how or where to start.)

code: (after binding to ldap and authenticating, this block is triggered)

```
// verify binding
    if ($ldap_bind) {
    echo "
<head>
<link - stylesheet \link>
</head>
<form class=\"form-horizontal\" action\"form.php\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">
<fieldset>
<body>
html code....lots of div boxes
<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
Various Jquery functions that hide/unhide div boxes
});
</script>
</body>
</fieldset>
</form>
";

            } else {
                echo "<p class='text-error'>Unable to log you in:</p>";
```

Comment: Just break in and out of php `if ($ldap_bind) { ?>html<?php  } ...`

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you've got? One thing I notice is that you've got `<form>` and `<fieldset>` elements between `</head>` and `<body>`. They should both be inside the `<body>`.

Comment: Running the code I have on it's own allows my jQuery functions that unhide/hide div sections based on other div section selections to work.  But when I take that and place it all in the echo, those functions no longer work. All the hidden divs stay hidden.

Comment: It might help to look at the HTML that is rendered after the PHP output. I see no reason using PHP would distinctly prevent JavaScript from working, unless the PHP outputs invalid HTML (which it does, based on your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML structure is quite mixed up. Have a look at how I "reorganized" it below and feel free to read tutorials like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics#Anatomy_of_an_HTML_document) about it.

Second, you can use the PHP tags (`<?php` and `?>`) to avoid the multi-line `echo` and all the quote escaping mess. What is outside these tags won't be processed by PHP and sent as-is to the browser. So you can write "usual" HTML there.

Third, having your scripts outside HTML like `<form>` is a good practice. And the library calls commonly are placed in the `<head>`... But it's also common to have it near the end of the document, just above `</html>`, instead of the `<head>`. For sure, not oddly everywhere in the markup.

```
// verify binding
if ($ldap_bind) {
  ?>
  <head>
  <title>My page title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="...">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
        html code....lots of div boxes
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //Various jQuery functions that hide/unhide div boxes
    });
    </script>
  </body>
  <?php
} else {
  ?>
  <p class='text-error'>Unable to log you in:</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tips! I laid my html out like you have shown, and escaped the php for that block. It works great!  I was worried it wouldn't allow all the form data to be used by the follow on php script that isn't shown, but it worked just fine! Thank you again!